# I'm trying to get a centered background image on one section only

Tags: html, css

I have several section titles, however they are managed globally under the "section-title" class. I tried a wrapper, but it changed all the settings.
Here is an example of what I am wanting to do -http://demo.webisir.com/?product=the_tattooist basically I want to add a different centered image on each section I have.

```
    <div id="last-works" class="section">

        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>Last Works</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="content container">

    .section-title {
     margin: -80px 0 80px 0;
     padding: 80px 0;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
I'm not seeing an attempt here. You don't have a background image in the provided code. What's the **actual** problem? Is it the centering of a background image? Is it targeting a specific instance of `.section-title`? Or both?

Comment: Yes I want to target this specific .section-title. There are 4 total and i'd like to add a different image behind each section. like this http://demo.webisir.com/?product=the_tattooist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css class.

```
.section-title:nth-child(1) {
     background: url('firstphoto.jpg') center no-repeat;
}

.section-title:nth-child(2) {
     background: url('secondphoto.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
```

You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GillesCoeman/cvekm8d3/1/).

Comment: I'm wanting to do something like this http://demo.webisir.com/?product=the_tattooist - basically I want to add the glyphs behind the section titles.

Comment: That is not at all what I understood from your explanation, let change it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not great at explaining. There are several of these "section-title"s here is another one. I would like to put a different one on each section---------<div id="artists" class="section">

                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h2>Our Artists</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content container">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4 artist">

Comment: Can you add a full example to your question? Why not just use `#artists .section-title { }` if every section has it's own unique parent?

Comment: That worked in getting the image in the background, but it added the same one to all sections. Even though I changed the second child, I added the example in my question.                     
.section-title:nth-child(1) {
     background:  url(../img/glyphs/diamond-dark.png) center no-repeat;
   background-size: 10%;
}

.section-title:nth-child(2) {
     background: url(../img/glyphs/anchor-dark.png) center no-repeat;
   background-size: 20%;
}

Comment: like this? 
.section-title {
    margin: -80px 0 80px 0;
    padding: 80px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    
    
}

.section-title h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 900;
    
}

.section-title.transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}



.section-title #studio {

    background-image: url(../img/glyphs/anchor-dark.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 20%;
 
}

Comment: this worked! Thanks so much for your help, I know I wasn't great at explaining it.                                   #artists .section-title   {
    min-height: 150px;
    background: url(../img/glyphs/corona-dark.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-align: center;